# Can a druid use a Sending Stone while in Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, druid, wild-shape

Can a druid use a *sending stone* while in Wild Shape?

I'm torn on this, as *sending stones* are a magic item and would greatly enhance communication while scouting ahead.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No, because you still cast a spell from the item

Per the description of the [*sending stones*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/sending-stones):

> *Sending stones* come in pairs, with each smooth stone carved to match the other so the pairing is easily recognized. While you touch one stone, you can use an action to **cast the *sending* spell** from it. [...]

And the description for [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167) states: "You can’t cast spells". At least not until you're high enough level.

#### Food for thought

The *sending stones* only work once per day. You can Wild Shape twice per rest. So you could Wild Shape, do your recon, revert to normal, use the stone, Wild Shape again, and then head back to the party.